# JQuery – Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseevent

I'm a photographer and not a code expert but I've been trying for a while to make this work – it's an animated image that achieves the effect of a GIF without the restraints of 256 colours and the pixelation/noise that comes with it.
It works by translating the background image inside a fixed div.
The Javascript is underneath and the way it works with one of my images can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/MXWgZ/

HTML:

```
<div id='image_box' onmouseover='start_rotate();' onmouseout='stop_rotate();'></div>
```

CSS

```
#image_box {
margin-left:20px;
width:533px;
height:800px;
background-image:url('http://www.studioprivate.co.uk/droguslong2.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:0px;}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var curr_pos = 0; //current background-position
var timer_id = 0;

function rotate_img() {
if (curr_pos == -13858) curr_pos = 0; //if 360 degree done
else curr_pos = curr_pos - 533;
$("#image_box").css("background-position", curr_pos + "px"); //move bacground to the left by 533px
if (curr_pos == -13858) curr_pos = 0;}

function start_rotate() {
timer_id = setInterval(rotate_img, 80);}
function stop_rotate() {
clearInterval(timer_id);}
```

Now, it works fine except for when it gets to the end, where it seems to show for a split second the white background instead of jumping straight to the beginning. Is there any way to get rid of this? I feel like it disrupts the flow.

Another question is – could I add another event onclick so that when clicking on the image, the background image is replaced with another one and animated like above? Where would that go in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Lot of magic numbers in there, which you should strive to eliminate. Also, can you make a http://jsfiddle.net, so it's easier for others to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing the calculations outside of the code (533px width * 26 slides = 13858px), why not turn these magic numbers into variables:

```
function nextSlide() {
  var slideWidth = 533;
  var slideCount = 26;

  var currentX = parseInt($imageContainer.css('background-position'), 10);
  currentX = (currentX - slideWidth) % (slideWidth * slideCount);

  $imageContainer.css('background-position', currentX);
}
```

The mod (%) operator removes the need for a confusing `if`/`else` block, and the properly named variables make the logic clear.

Another small change, rather than attaching your hover events directly to the html through `onmouseover`/`onmouseout`, you can use a jQuery event binding:

```
$imageContainer.hover(start_rotate, stop_rotate);
```

You can similarly attach a click event to change the image:

```
$imageContainer.click(function() {
  $imageContainer.css('background-image',
      'url("http://www.studioprivate.co.uk/newImage.jpg")');
  $imageContainer.css('background-position', 0);    
});
```

You'll have to do a make some adjustments to the `nextSlide` method if the new image has a different slideWidth or slideCount, but this example should get you on your way.

Bringing it all together - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXWgZ/1/)

Comment: That's great, thank you! Now I know this is another question altogether, but if I wanted so that on the first click it replaces the background image with a new one and then the second would return it back to the original, would that be much more complicated?

Comment: You can accomplish this with only a couple extra lines. Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXWgZ/4/).

Answer (score 1):

There are already JavaScript and jQuery tools that help you accomplish this:

- http://www.spritely.net
- http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel
- http://www.ajaxblender.com/jani.html
- http://spritespin.ginie.eu/

Comment: Hey! This doesn't directly answer my problem so I couldn't choose it as the answer, but it's an amazing resource. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be more dynamic with the background-position amount, that way you aren't doing guess work with the numbers. Also, you would get a white screen if you left the if block at the full width of the image because the function would run one more time regardless of the if block. Subtract the width from the ending background-position to avoid that:

```
// With curr_pos like this, you have a number generated from JavaScript rather than guesswork
var curr_pos = parseInt($("#image_box").css("background-position").slice(0,-2), 10); 

if (curr_pos <= (-13858+533)) { //Take out that nasty white space by accounting for one less frame
    curr_pos = 0+"px";
} else {
    curr_pos = curr_pos - 533 + "px";
}
```

Also, since you are using jQuery, you might as well harness it's power of selectors. The following code adds event handlers using jQuery rather than directly in the markup. Your click function is incorporated:

```
$("#image_box").hover(function() {
    timer_id = setInterval(rotate_img, 200);
}, function() {
    clearInterval(timer_id);
}).click(function() {
    $(this).css(/*change background stuff*/);  
}); // This settles your click idea
```

This leaves your markup looking like this:

```
<div id='image_box'></div>
```

#### A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/9vjqW/5/) everything

Comment: Thanks Christopher! Had a read, but @ljfranklin 's method made a bit more sense for me, as it's less code and more maths. with thise, you lost me from the .slice, as I've never used it :P